# Body class on forum page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to show category on body class.
But now I'm facing problems on BBPress forum page. I'm getting Notices "non-object, undefined offset..."

How to exclude BBPress pages from this? I need to have just normal body classes when on forum pages.

```
add_filter('body_class','top_cat_body_class');

function top_cat_body_class($classes) {
if( is_single() ) :
    global $post;
    $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if( count( $cats ) > 1 ) {
        return array('genericClass');
    }
    else {
        $cat_anc = get_ancestors( $cats[0]->term_id, 'category' );
        $top_cat = array_merge( array($cats[0]->term_id), $cat_anc );
        $top_cat = array_pop( $top_cat );
        return array(get_category($top_cat)->slug);
    }
elseif( is_category() ) :
    $cat_anc = get_ancestors( get_query_var('cat'), 'category' );
    $top_cat = array_merge( array(get_query_var('cat')), $cat_anc );
    $top_cat = array_pop( $top_cat );
    return array(get_category($top_cat)->slug);
else :
    return $classes;
endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bbPress Conditional Tags](https://codex.bbpress.org/bbpress-conditional-tags/) and add to the beginning of your `top_cat_body_class` function code something like

```
if (function_exists('is_bbpress') AND is_bbpress()) return $classes;
```

Hope it helps!